# TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayAvatarURL' of undefined: Get this error when trying to ping another person to get their avatar

Tags: javascript, discord.js, undefined

```
    } else if (command === 'avatar') {
        const target = message.mentions.users.first();
       
        if (target) {
            const userTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
            message.channel.send(message.userTarget.displayAvatarURL());
        } else if (!target) {
            message.channel.send(message.author.displayAvatarURL());
        } 
     }
 });
```

The else if statement works fine but when there is a person to going to get the avatar of that person it just doesn't work.

Comment: Hey new guy... There is so much information missing in your question. Such as: what is `message` object? Please upload all relevant files. And check this forum's rules for how to ask a good question here

Comment: Your message object doesn't have the author property as you supposed in your code. That's why you are getting the error. Can you post a `console.log` of your message object?

Comment: I aim to ping another person for their avatar so I dont want an author property instead the actual target's property. Its fine another has already answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) has no `userTarget` property. If you want to get the avatar url of the target `member`, then access the [`user`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=user) property of the returned [`member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) and call the [display method](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=displayAvatarURL) there:

`userTarget.user.displayAvatarURL()`

Alternatively, your `target` variable already stores the target user, so you don't need to get their member object and store it in `userTarget`. You can just call:

`target.displayAvatarURL()`

Comment: When I do 
  } else if (command === 'avatar') {
    const target = message.mentions.users.first();
      if (target) {
     const userTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
     message.channel.send(message.target.displayAvatarURL());

   } else if (!target) {
     message.channel.send(message.author.displayAvatarURL());
     } 
 
   }
 });
I get displayAvatarURLof undefined

Comment: @A5TR0N0MICZ Don't do `message.target.displayAvatarURL()`. Just use `target.displayAvatarURL()`. [This](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) is the object your `target` variable is storing. As you can see from the link, it has the `displayAvatarURL()` method.